# Does the iCloud API allow music library access from iOS?

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, icloud, icloud-api

I understand that not all information is official yet, and that some information about the new OS is under lock and key, but is it publicly known yet whether the iCloud API will support iOS app access to the user's cloud music library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has not been publicly announced at this time.  You can find the answer either in the documentation or the Apple Developer Forums though.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you can only have access to your app's documents in iCloud.

Comment: can you back this assertion with some URLs? thanks (until you do this, I'm going to downvote your answer)